# Django 1.9.5 and easy_thumbnails late loading and south

Tags: django

I have some problems using django easy thumbnails.

First: Thumbnails doesn't load in first time. This looks like easy_thumbnails doesn't generate thumbnail in a first time. And then all OK.

Second error is

> There is no South database module 'south.db.mysql' for your database.
>   Please either choose a supported database, check for
>   SOUTH_DATABASE_ADAPTER[S] settings, or remove South from
>   INSTALLED_APPS.

Comment: I can apply migrations only if comment easy_thumbnails package in INSTALLED_APPS

Comment: That error message tells you what to do. Remove south

Comment: I don't have any south apps. Only easy_thumbnails.

Comment: "emove South from INSTALLED_APPS."

Comment: INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'ws4redis',
    'easy_thumbnails',
    'compressor'
]

Comment: If you google "There is no South database module" you will get a lot of hits. What worked for some people was `python -m pip uninstall south`.

Answer (score 0):

Problem with south was in south in my environment. But removing south doesn't give me some results. Just error:

```
ImportError: No module named south.db
```

Then I've reinstall easy_thumbnails and migrations was rewrited on Django migrations:

```
pip uninstall South
pip uninstall easy_thumbnails
pip install easy_thumbnails
```